# Can grouped products use backorders in Magento CE 1.7?

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

Can grouped products use  the backorder functionality in magento?

I have created a grouped product in backend. But there is no any place there to enable backorders for the product.  I have changed the Availability message in frontend for `simple products` and enabled the Add to cart button as well. How can I do the same thing for `grouped products`?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should ensure that the simple products associated with the group product are available for back-order. As long as the related simple products are saleable and the qty can go below 0 you should be able to take back-orders for grouped products as well.

So in each of your simple products go to inventory tab and set back-orders to "Allow Qty Below 0" and insure that stock availability is set to "In Stock"

If you are using another extension for displaying back-order messages I would refer to the extension documentation to see if they support grouped and configurable products.